# Html.RenderAction - the controller for path '/' was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Using ASP.NET MVC 2 and and Html.RenderAction in my masterpage implemented as below throws an error with "the controller for path '/' was not found":

I'm a bit of a newbie, do i have to do something in RegisterRoutes to make this work?

```
<% Html.RenderAction("TeaserList", "SportEventController"); %>

public class SportEventController : Controller
{
    public string TeaserList()
    {
        return "hi from teaserlist";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure but I guess the following things are wrong:

- <strike>your TeaserList method should return an [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx)</strike>
- the call to RenderAction should be `RenderAction("TeaserList", "SportEvent")` without the Controller suffix

Comment: i will crawl back into my shell, it was the "Controller" suffix, thanks Martin 
...BTW: it doesn't have to return a ActionResult, returning a string works just fine...try it and see!

Comment: Watch out for security issues when returning user strings! (which doesn't seem like the case, but had to mention it..)

Answer (score 0):

In order for that to work, `TeaserList()` has to be a method that returns an `ActionResult` like:

```
`
public virtual ActionResult TeaserList()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

`

If you want "Hi from teaserlist" then you could have that in a View called TeaserList or you could add

```
`ViewData["teaserList"] = "hi from teaserlist";`
```

and have it rendered in your view.

Comment: it doesn't have to return a ActionResult, returning a string works just fine...try it and see!

Comment: While that is true (in essence, your controller turns all pubic methods into Actions anyway), I believe the spirit is to return ActionResults, and that way (for testing, as example) you could return any subtype. So in your case, you could return a ContentResult.